# How To change the iframe url in Ionic 2 With Typescript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have tried this but nothing worked. please help !

```
    var el = (<HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById("siteFrame"));
el.setAttribute('src',"https://www.google.co.in");
```

and i had also tried this

```
el.src="https://www.google.co.in";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property). In your html...

```
[src]="https://www.google.co.in"
```

No need for the getElement....